# Excel. Data type -> Geography. Why are coordinates for large cities missing?

Tags: excel, maps

In Excel if you have a city in a cell, it is possible to go to Data tab and then choose Geography as data type.

[image]

This will allow to get map coordinates: longitude and latitude.

[image]

However, it might be able to recognize smaller cities, while some major cities are missing. For example, here are two cities in Hungary where it cannot recognize the capital. Similarly, it can recognize Stuttgart in Germany but not Berlin. My problem is that I have a VBA macro that calculates the distance between two cities, and I am using this method. Does anyone have any idea about the logic - why are some major cities missing? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with programming? Using Excel is not programming...

Comment: Try asking on Superuser or on Microsoft forums. Anyway it's Microsoft, what do you expect?

Comment: That is typical Microsoft BS really. I just tried it and aside from the fact that it made me disconnect from all my Microsoft accounts before wanting to work... it's just terrible. A Microsoft software talking to a Microsoft API, via a dedicated feature and miserably failing to return consistent results for whatever obscure reason. I am able to geocode a 300 inhabitants village, but not the country's capital city. That's almost funny. Google has a geocoding API, so does Nominatim and others. I bet you'll find at least one that is capable of geocoding Budapest!

Comment: Thank you! Well, as I mention in the description, I have a large dataset with "from" and "to" addresses, and my code cannot estimate the distance because some of the cities are missing. But yes, it is more an Excel question. Thank you for the comments - I have now asked on Microsoft forum.